# How to make payments on recurring product automatically(RESOLVED)

Tags: 7, commerce

I have drupal 7 and commerce modules. I'm using Stripe payment system with module commerce_stripe. Customer's card details are stored in file (commerce card in file).
Site sells recurring products.

My question is:
can I make payments on recurring products automatically without user agreement?
And if I can how should I do it?

Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE

Found how recurring entities and card on file work. After user bought subscription first time his card data saves into file to use it in later payments. When user should pay for subscription again cron `commerce_recurring_cron` should run. This cron checks recurring entities and if it's time to pay creates an order with status pending.

When this cron runs once again it charges payments and necessary amount of money debited from users account.

So everything I need is processed and my customer is happy.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Card on File module, that means you're storing tokens that point to card data stored securely by the payment gateway itself. What you then need is to combine that with Commerce Recurring or the Commerce License suite to create the schedule for recurring charges and Commerce Dunning to react to payment failures.

Answer (score -1):

Storing credit card details isn't very safe and allowed unless you have an application which is PCI complied and as well the hosting.

Anyway, as you are using Stripe, you should have a look at this: https://stripe.com/subscriptions